# Powershell script : get track ID from a mkv to be used in a mkvmerge command with reorganised track or dismissing unwanted tracks

Tags: powershell, mkv

I'm working on a PowerShell script to merge some external subtitle file with a mkv, and naming correctly the different tracks, and re-ordering them. That part works great if the tracks id are the same for all mkv... It requires me to identify before the track id and set them in my script.
Ok, that's not the fast way, but my script works fine, and can reorder the tracks as I want.
I managed to build a personalized command of mkvmerge.

But for some mkv, the track id are messed up... And I have not a small amount like those...
So, in order to treat in mass, I would like to get, via a script, the track id for the video, the audio in English, French or Japanese (if there is those tracks), and the same for subtitles in En and Fr, forced or not.
In my best hopes, it would be great to have an array with the track id, the track type and the lang track.
I may be able to manage to search for a specific language in this array, I hope it's possible, right?

Comment: I managed to get a JSON file from MediaInfo CLI, and opened it into a variable with `$JSON_object = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$JSON_file" | ConvertFrom-Json`
I can get some values like this :
`$VideoCount = $JSON_object.media.track.VideoCount`
And now, I'm looking to search for the audio type, or video type.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a way to do what I need.
It's maybe not very clean, bit it seems to work.

```shell
############################################################################################
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Début du script de test." -ForegroundColor "black" -BackgroundColor "white"
Write-Host ""

$MediaInfo = "`"path_to\MediaInfo.exe`""
$sourceDirectory_1 = "path_to_sourceDirectory1"
# $sourceDirectory_1_log = "path_to_sourceDirectory1_log"
$VideoExtension_1 = "mkv"
$MKV_1_name = "my_mkv_name"
$MKV_1 = $sourceDirectory_1 + "\" + $MKV_1_name + ".$VideoExtension_1"

# Values to set to what we want to keep :
$NB_Audio_MKV1 = 2
$AudioTrack_1_Lang = "ja"
$AudioTrack_2_Lang = "fr"
$AudioTrack_Default_Lang = "ja"

# Values witch will be found with MediaInfo JSON
$video_id = ""
$AudioTrack_1_ID = ""
$AudioTrack_2_ID = ""
$JSON_video_position = ""       # To use with $JSON_object.media.Track[ ]
$JSON_audio_1_position = ""     # To use with $JSON_object.media.Track[ ]
$JSON_audio_2_position = ""     # To use with $JSON_object.media.Track[ ]

# $JSON_file = "$sourceDirectory_1_log\$MKV_1_name.json"
# $MediaInfo_arguments = "--output=JSON --LogFile=`"$JSON_file`""
$MediaInfo_arguments = "--output=JSON"
$command_info = "& $MediaInfo $MediaInfo_arguments `"$MKV_1`""
# Launch begin...
$json_output = Invoke-Expression $command_info
# Write-Host "`$json_output = `n$json_output" -ForegroundColor "green"
# $JSON_object = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$JSON_file" | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSON_object = $json_output | ConvertFrom-Json


$i = 0      # Counter for video track detected
$j = 0      # Counter for audio track detected
$k = 0      # Counter for audio tracks kept
$l = 0      # Counter for track position
$JSON_VideoCount = $JSON_object.media.Track[0].VideoCount
$JSON_AudioCount = $JSON_object.media.Track[0].AudioCount

foreach ( $track in $JSON_object.media.Track ) {
    # Note :
    # The reel track ID is 1 minus the ID get in JSON...

    # Check if there is a bug in the script
    if ( $j -gt $JSON_AudioCount ) {
        Write-Host "There is a problem in Audio Track detection from JSON !! Need to debug this !!" -ForegroundColor "White" -BackgroundColor "DarkRed"
        Exit
    }
    elseif ( $i -gt $JSON_VideoCount ) {
        Write-Host "There is a problem in Video Track detection from JSON !! Need to debug this !!" -ForegroundColor "White" -BackgroundColor "DarkRed"
        Exit
    }

    if ( $track."@type" -match "Video" ) {
        $video_id = $track.id - 1
        $i++
        $JSON_video_position = $l
    }
    elseif ( $track."@type" -match "Audio" ) {
        $j++

        if (( $track."Language" -match "$AudioTrack_1_Lang" ) -And ( $AudioTrack_1_ID -eq "" ) -And ( $k -ne $NB_Audio_MKV1)) {
            $AudioTrack_1_ID = $track.id - 1
            $k++
            $JSON_audio_1_position = $l
        }
        elseif (( $track."Language" -match "$AudioTrack_2_Lang" ) -And ( $AudioTrack_2_ID -eq "" ) -And ( $k -ne $NB_Audio_MKV1)) {
            $AudioTrack_2_ID = $track.id - 1
            $k++
            $JSON_audio_2_position = $l
        }
        else {
            if (( $AudioTrack_1_ID -eq "" ) -And ( $AudioTrack_2_ID -eq "" )) {
                write-host "There is no audio tracks that match your specifications." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
            }
            else {
                write-host "There is no audio tracks that match your specifications." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
            }

        }
    }
    $l++    # Increment number of track processed
}

write-host "`t`$video_id = $video_id" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
write-host "`t`$AudioTrack_1_ID = $AudioTrack_1_ID`tLang set in the script = $AudioTrack_1_Lang" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
write-host "`t`$AudioTrack_2_ID = $AudioTrack_2_ID`tLang set in the script = $AudioTrack_2_Lang" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"


Write-Host "`nFin du script de test." -ForegroundColor "black" -BackgroundColor "white"
```

I'll integrate this into my main script, and see if there is some side effects :)

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.